# I get a different result when I try and calculate the mean-variance formula of risky and riskless asset

Tags: variance, finance, weighted-mean

I'm having trouble seeing how the expected return of a two asset portfolio, where the weight of the risk-free asset is positive, but the weight of the risky asset is negative, results in the final formula below. Whenever I try this myself, I end up with something different from the book.

The formulas I have for the expected return on the portfolio and the standard deviation are

$\bar{R}_{p} = x_{1}r_{f}+x_{2}\bar{r}_{2}$

$\sigma_{p} = x_{2}\sigma_{2}$

I can see that when the risky asset weight is negative that I end up with

$x_{2} = -\frac{\sigma_{p}}{\sigma_{2}}$

and therefore the risk-free weight is

$x_{1} = 1+\frac{\sigma_{p}}{\sigma_{2}}$

But when I substitute $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ into $\bar{R}_{p}$ I don't get this, what is in the book

$\bar{R}_{p} = r_{f}-\frac{\bar{r}_{2}-r_{f}}{\sigma_{2}}\sigma_{p}$

But I do get this

$=(1+\frac{\sigma_{p}}{\sigma_{2}})r_{f}+(-\frac{\sigma_{p}}{\sigma_{2}})\bar{r}_{2}$

$=(r_{f}+\frac{\sigma_{p}r_{f}}{\sigma_{2}})+(-\frac{\sigma_{p}\bar{r}_{2}}{\sigma_{2}})$

$=r_{f}+\frac{\sigma_{p}r_{f}}{\sigma_{2}}-\frac{\sigma_{p}\bar{r}_{2}}{\sigma_{2}}$

$=r_{f}+\frac{\sigma_{p}r_{f}-\sigma_{p}\bar{r}_{2}}{\sigma_{2}}$

$=r_{f}+\frac{r_{f}-\bar{r}_{2}}{\sigma_{2}}\sigma_{p}$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There does not appear to be any substantial question here: you reproduce what it in the book; nothing is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with the signs of your equations, since the expression in the book

$\bar{R}_{p} = r_{f}-\frac{\bar{r}_{2}-r_{f}}{\sigma_{2}}\sigma_{p}$

is the same as the one you found

$\bar{R}_{p} = r_{f}+\frac{r_{f}-\bar{r}_{2}}{\sigma_{2}}\sigma_{p}$